# Salesforce DX: source:force:status shows every component as a "Local Add"

Tags: salesforcedx

Somehow my sourcePathInfos.json gets out of sync with my scratch org. I haven't been able to identify a specific event that correlates to this, but occasionally when I `sfdx force:source:push` it tries to push every component in my project, and `sfdx force:source:status` says that every component is a "Local Add". Even after pushing every component it doesn't update the statuses and will subsequently try pushing everything again. Anyone else have this happen and know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. I have multiple Unlocked packages and in my sfdx-project.json file, I had those listed in package directories. My default package directory was listed as one level up from those, and every time I pulled source into the project it would drop everything into the default directory which resulted in it thinking everything was new and not yet in my scratch org.